# How to make GUI with kinect SDK Application SkeletonBasics-D2D?

Tags: c++, opencv, sdk, kinect

I have made a project using SkeletonBasics-D2D of Kinect XBOX 360 in C++ on gesture recognition. I have also used OpenCV in this project. Now I want to make GUI of this project for better representation. But I am not able to do this using Windows Form Application..I am new to Visual Studio 2010 and kinect.Kindly help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using WPF instead of a Windows Form Application? The Kinect for Microsoft SDK samples use WPFs due to its stronger capabilities with displaying/dealing with visual elements. The learning curve isn't that huge to go from Windows Form to WPF imo, and there are plenty of blogs that can help you get started or answer most questions you'll have to start off:

Here's a list of WPF blogs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/03/12/wpf-bloggers.aspx
My favorite is the 2000 things blog.

In WPF Kinect applications, there's typically an Image element in the .XAML side whose source is set to a WriteableBitmap property in the back-end code. On each Color Stream ready event (or any stream for that matter) you can write the new set of pixels to the WriteableBitmap and the WPF image element is instantly updated. I haven't tried using Windows Forms but I think it's a lot more work for a less-clean product.

Comment: Also, if you install the Kinect SDK and Toolkit, you'll have a lot of sample projects to help you get started.

Comment: For using Skeleton Basics-WPF I have to convert the complete code from C++ to C# as I have used Skeleton Basics -D2D Application of Kinect SDK v 1.8.0.